# Get value of a dynamically populated select

Tags: jquery

I have a `<select>` that gets populated from the database:

```
  $(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "lib/deleteuser.getusernames.php",
        async: "false",
        success: function(response){
            $("#users").append('<option>' +  response.split(",").join("</option><option>") + '</option>');
        }
    }); 
  });
```

(this works fine by the way)

Now, I'm trying to take the value of the `<select>` and use it to run another query, but all that gets returned is nothing, or 'undefined'.

Here's what I have tried:

```
var username = $("#users option:selected").val();
var username = $("#users :selected").val();
var username = $("#users option:selected").text();
var username = $("#users :selected").text();
```

I understand that `.val()` only gets the value of an input, but in this case does the option text still count as input? I tried `.text()` just in case, but still came up with nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to get the value of the inputs before the ajax is complete, you should change `async: "false",` to  `async: false`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `$("#users").val()`?

The [`.val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) gets (or sets) the value of form elements including inputs, selects and textareas. You can use it directly on your select element rather than trying to get to the chosen option with `option:selected`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if it can help

```
$("#users > option:selected").attr("value")
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

As undefined said, it looks like your selectors may be ahead of the async GET. You can try this if you want to retain the async behavior:

```
$(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "lib/deleteuser.getusernames.php",
    success: function(response){
      $("#users").append('<option>' +  response.split(",").join("</option><option>") + '</option>');
      userSelect();
    }
  });

  var userVal,
      userText,
      userElem;

  var userSelect = function () {
    $( '#users' ).change(function(){
      userVal = $( 'option:selected', this ).val();
      userText = $( 'option:selected', this ).text();
      userElem = $( 'option:selected', this );
    });
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$('#users option').html();
```

which works like innerHTML? Hope this helps.